# java.lang.RuntimeException Error and App Crashing On Google Play Logcat Added

Tags: java, android-studio, proguard, google-play-console, android-r8

My app works on test device but crashes on playstore with this ERROR:

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:4048)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:4312)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute
> (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
> (TransactionExecutor.java:135)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
> (TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2571)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)   at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8741)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:571)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:1067) Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
> (BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
> (ClassLoader.java:379)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
> (ClassLoader.java:312)   at
> android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity
> (AppComponentFactory.java:95)   at
> androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity
> (CoreComponentFactory.java:45)   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1328)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:4035)

I thought it might have something to do with proguard so I tried disabling it by creating a `proguaurd-rules.pro` file in platform>android>app so the app file contains the proguard-rules.pro I honestly copied and pasted it there from another project so maybe this has caused an issue but I didn't think it would.

After I added that file I went in to the build.gradle and added this code:

```
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

That did nothing for the crash so I went back and changed the code to this:

```
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled false
                useproguard false
                proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                useproguard false
                proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

the crashes are still occurring and I am still getting the same error message on the play console, what am I doing wrong? Is this even a proguard issue or maybe something else?

update: I've since added multidex support by adding the library and enabling multidex in the defaultconfig and that did nothhing for the crashes.

here is the logcat:

```
2023-04-17 19:32:57.775 11564-11564/? I/Calculator.FRE: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-04-17 19:32:58.821 11564-11564/? E/Calculator.FRE: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2023-04-17 19:32:58.824 11564-11564/? W/Calculator.FRE: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2023-04-17 19:33:05.098 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Calculator.FRE: Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
2023-04-17 19:33:05.228 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Calculator.FRE: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on HeapTrim for 130.343ms
2023-04-17 19:33:05.525 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-04-17 19:33:05.555 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2023-04-17 19:33:05.555 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2023-04-17 19:33:05.581 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.BMICalculator.FREE, PID: 11564
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.BMICalculator.FREE/com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2023-04-17 19:33:05.676 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.678 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.688 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.705 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11564 SIG: 9
2023-04-17 19:33:05.552 11564-11564/? W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:82): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6318 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c153,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.BMICalculator.FREE2023-04-17 19:32:57.775 11564-11564/? I/Calculator.FRE: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-04-17 19:32:58.821 11564-11564/? E/Calculator.FRE: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2023-04-17 19:32:58.824 11564-11564/? W/Calculator.FRE: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2023-04-17 19:33:05.098 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Calculator.FRE: Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
2023-04-17 19:33:05.228 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Calculator.FRE: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on HeapTrim for 130.343ms
2023-04-17 19:33:05.525 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-04-17 19:33:05.555 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2023-04-17 19:33:05.555 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2023-04-17 19:33:05.581 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.BMICalculator.FREE, PID: 11564
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.BMICalculator.FREE/com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BMICalculator.FREE.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.BMICalculator.FREE-7yb4W7NdqCUw_5mYxhAjRA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2023-04-17 19:33:05.676 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.678 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.688 11564-11596/com.BMICalculator.FREE D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-04-17 19:33:05.705 11564-11564/com.BMICalculator.FREE I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11564 SIG: 9
2023-04-17 19:33:05.552 11564-11564/? W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:82): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6318 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c153,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.BMICalculator.FREE
```